# Implementing DKIM on a domain with multiple Salesforce orgs

Tags: email, deliverability, dkim

A client of ours has **2 separate Salesforce orgs**. Their organization uses **one email domain** for sending out emails (e.g staff**@company.com**). Their users send out emails from Salesforce using this domain address.

If we were to **implement DKIM** on the email domain, how do we do the DKIM settings on **both** Salesforce orgs? **If we only carry out the settings on one Salesforce org, will it affect the email deliverability of the other org?**

Comment: Is this Marketing Cloud or core SF platform